# buildr - share profiles.yaml file across projects

Tags: buildr

> The profiles file is a YAML file called profiles.yaml that you place
>   in the same directory as the Buildfile

I was wondering is it possible to share the same profiles file for more than one project, i.e. specifying a different location to where to find the profiles.yaml file as opposed to defaulting to the same directory as the build file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution I ended up with was to load my own profiles.yaml file:

```
require 'yaml'

def profile
  profiles = YAML.load_file('../../profiles.yaml')
  profiles[ENV['BUILDR_ENV']] ||= {}
end

puts "env:" << profile['propname']
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm afraid I don't have a satisfactory answer.

You could use git-submodules, braid, svn externals (or a plain old symbolic link) to do the trick.

Looking at the code, we don't permit using a different path for the profiles file at this point.

If you would like this behavior to change, I would suggest you enter an enhancement request for Buildr and consider providing a patch.